# deploy rails 4 with phusion passenger and strange error come out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger

I want to deploy rails 4 app with passenger ( 4.0.35 ), but after i had set everything locally.
It supposed to work perfectly. But i gotta this error

```
/home/god/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require': cannot load such file -- /phusion_passenger/platform_info/operating_system (LoadError)
    <br>.......<br>
[ pid=2032 thr=139914783938304 file=ext/apache2/Hooks.cpp:862 time=2014-02-24 18:21:23.334 ]: Unexpected error in mod_passenger: Cannot spawn application '/home/god/project/news.nxbtch.com': Could not read from the spawn server: Connection reset by peer (104)
  Backtrace:
     (empty)
```

**I change passenger from version 4.0.37  to 4.0.36 and 4.0.35 , the same error. so it must be my config error! help me!**

**RVM Info**

```
ruby-2.1.0:

  system:
    uname:       "Linux god-machine 3.11.0-17-generic #31-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 3 21:52:43 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux"
    system:      "ubuntu/13.10/x86_64"
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 4.2.45(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)"
    zsh:         "/usr/bin/zsh => zsh 5.0.2 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.25.18 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]"
    updated:      "4 days 22 hours 48 minutes 8 seconds ago"
    path:         "/home/god/.rvm"


  environment:
    PATH:         "/home/god/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin:/home/god/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/bin:/home/god/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin:/home/god/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/god/.rvm/bin"
    GEM_HOME:     "/home/god/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0"
    GEM_PATH:     "/home/god/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0:/home/god/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/home/god/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0"
    IRBRC:        "/home/god/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       ""
```

**passenger version:**

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

passenger (4.0.35)
```

**apache config:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin *******
    ServerName ruby.local.com
    DocumentRoot /home/god/tmp/ruby.local.com/public
    PassengerRuby /home/god/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/wrappers/ruby

    <Directory /home/god/tmp/ruby.local.com/public>
        #AllowOverride all
        Allow from all
        Options -MultiViews
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**and i had point ruby.local.com to 127.0.0.1**

**Thanks !**